# Installing SharePoint 2013 without Active Directory

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, active-directory

We are planning to install SharePoint 2013 on single box for public web site. Web site is not having very heavy traffic. Website will be install on **cloud**, hosting company is denying to give us domain account due to security issue.

So now my question is,

> Is it possible to install SharePoint 2013 without domain account.

I know that lot of people has done it without domain account but when I was going through some Microsoft technical articles. I found that it is not recommended.

1. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262243.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

> **Security**
>   The server farm account is used to create and
>   access your configuration database. It also acts as the application
>   pool identity account for the SharePoint Central Administration
>   application pool, and it is the account under which the Microsoft
>   SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer service runs. The SharePoint
>   Products Configuration Wizard adds this account to the SQL Server
>   Login accounts, the SQL Server dbcreator server role, and the SQL
>   Server securityadmin server role. The user account that you specify as
>   the service account has to be a domain user account. However, it does
>   not have to be a member of any specific security group on your
>   front-end web servers or your database servers. We recommend that you
>   follow the principle of least-privilege and specify a user account
>   that is not a member of the Administrators group on your front-end web
>   servers or your database servers.

2. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/022507f9-3555-43fd-a93e-faef6da5d59e/installing-sharepoint-2013-without-active-directory

So please guide with some pros and cons in my scenario or what is other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, MSFT is not supporting this type of deployment, [which they mentioned here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2764086)

- If a deployment is not supported by Microsoft,then if you have any issue with environment and contact to Microsoft they will refuse to help you.
- You have to perform testing in your farm, becuase Micrsoft will not testing this scenario. i.e when you apply CU or SP.
- couple of service application will not work i.e User Profile.
- The new app model of SharePoint 2013 does require proper DNS configuration supporting Active Directory.

Only advantage i am seeing is, saves lots of money for those who don’t have sufficient financial resource to invest a real server or a powerful computer for testing.

[Source](http://thuansoldier.net/?p=3044)

Comment: Waqas that's good explanation, In my case I don't have to use User Profile. But still I am confuse that without Active Directory should I go or making same virtual machine to install Active directory, SQL Server 2012 with SP2 and SharePoint 2013 with SP1 is good idea.

Comment: for production, i should not go without active directory

Comment: Do you think it can be good idea that making same virtual machine to install Active directory, SQL Server 2012 with SP2 and SharePoint 2013 with SP1 for low traffic website.

Comment: yes, it is way better then without AD. I will go with it

Comment: Note that no Microsoft service requires Microsoft DNS nor Active Directory integrated DNS. You can use Bind or Infoblox instead, for example. Installing SharePoint on a Domain Controller is an unsupported installation scenario and should not be done.

Comment: @TrevorSeward I came up with other idea. Client is also providing me development server. So I can install domain controller on development server and use that domain controller for Production Server. Kindly give your thoughts on it.

Comment: What u mean by development server? Will it be up all the time or it will use for the development of other stuff? Rule is...for production make sure all yours resources are up all the time n according to Msft supported topology

Comment: I would re-set expectations with your client. Give them the minimum requirements and supported architecture, then go from there.